# How does this [t]ricky bracket expression in grep work?

Tags: command-line, bash, grep

I saw this one-liner recently:

```
$ ps -ef | grep [f]irefox 

thorsen   16730     1  1 Jun19 ?        00:27:27 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox ...
```

So it seems to return the list of processes with "firefox" in the data but leaving out the grep process itself, and therefore seems roughly equivalent to:

```
ps -ef |grep -v grep| grep firefox
```

I can't understand how it works though. I've looked at the man page on grep and elsewhere but haven't found an explanation.

And to compound the mystery if I run:

```
$ ps -ef | grep firefox  > data
$ grep [f]irefox data

thorsen   15820 28618  0 07:28 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto firefox
thorsen   16730     1  1 Jun19 ?        00:27:45 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox ....
```

the [t]rick seems to stop working!

Someone here will know what's going on I'm sure.

Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, are you sure that this is correct? ps -eaf|grep [fF]irefox would make more sense. This looks like a regular expression and in means match any one of the enclosed characters. Could be done also as range, e.g. [0-9]

Comment: Well yes. That was the  problem I was having: a character class containing only one character seemed pointless yet was producing a "mysterious" side effect! Anyway jokerdino has supplied a good explanation.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The square bracket expression is part of the <s>bash shell (and other shells as well)</s> grep's character class pattern matching.

The `grep` program by default understands POSIX basic regular expressions. With that you can define character classes. For example `ps -ef | grep [ab9]irefox` would find "**a**irefox", "**b**irefox", "**9**irefox" if those existed, but not "**ab**irefox".

The command `grep [a-zA-Z0-9]irefox` would even find all processes that start with exactly one letter or number and end in "irefox".

So `ps -ef | grep firefox` searches for lines with `firefox` in it. Since the grep process itself has "firefox" in it, grep finds that as well. By adding a `[]`, we are only searching for the character class "[f]" (which consists of only the letter "f" and is therefor equivalent to just an "f" without the brackets). The advantage of the brackets now is that the string "firefox" no longer appears in the grep command. Hence, grep itself won't show up in the grep result.

Because not very many people are familiar with square brackets as character class matching and regular expressions in general, the second result might look a little mysterious.

If you want to fix the second result, you can use them this way:

```
ps -ef | grep [f]irefox  > data
grep firefox data
```

[(Reference)](http://linuxcommando.blogspot.sg/2008/03/trick-grep-not-to-report-itself-in.html)

Comment: Hmm. It didn't occur to me that the [] was something interpreted by the shell BEFORE grep would even get a chance. Thanks for the explanation. All [m]yteries resolved.

Comment: Happy to help. Have a nice day :)

Comment: In bash, the square brackets _will_ be passed to grep if there is no match for the word they are in (i.e. no file named "firefox" in the current directory). However, grep also has character classes and [f] in grep is just the same as f.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. `ps -ef | grep '[f]irefox'` is confirmation I think, since the shell can't be modifying the argument, but the outcome is the same.

Comment: Actually in this case I don't think it's interpreted by the shell before grep. I think `[f]` is the regular expression pattern matching bracket for character classes. As in "[a-z0-9]irefox" grep would match "airefox" and "0irefox" as well. You can easily see that it is not a bash built-in since `echo $([f])` returns an error.

Comment: @con-f-use Thanks much for the correction and the edit. I was under the wrong opinion for quite some time. :/

Comment: The specific reason `[f]irefox` works for this purpose is that it is *not* expanded by the shell. When the shell expands `[f]irefox` to `firefox`, that causes `grep` to see `firefox`, and then `firefox` is part of `grep`'s command string, exactly as if `grep firefox` were run. But **it's good to keep shell pattern matching in mind**, particularly when scripting, because [if there is a file called `firefox` in the current directory](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10878943/), **then the shell *does* expand `[f]irefox` to `firefox`** and this method fails, i.e., the `grep` line from `ps` is shown.

Answer (score 11):

The reason is that the string

```
grep firefox
```

matches the pattern `firefox`, but the string

```
grep [f]irefox
```

does not match the pattern `[f]irefox` (which is equivalent to the pattern `firefox`).

That's why the first grep matches its own process command line, while the second doesn't.

Comment: This makes my head hurt even more

Comment: This answer is much better than the one chosen as accepted!

Answer (score 0):

Daniel's answer is spot-on, but there's one interesting complication brought to mind by jokerdino's (largely incorrect) answer about shell escaping.

First of all, notice that `ps`'s unfiltered output will contain a line corresponding to the `grep` process launched by your shell. If you're running `grep firefox` at the moment you run `ps`, you'll see it in the output:

```
$ ps
thorsen   15820 28618  0 07:28 pts/1    00:00:00 grep firefox
thorsen   23983     1  1 Jun19 ?        00:12:34 some other process ....
```

If you then take `ps`'s output and filter it through that `grep` process — grepping `ps`'s output for strings that match the regex `firefox` — then, well, that line will match!

```
$ ps | grep firefox
thorsen   15820 28618  0 07:28 pts/1    00:00:00 grep firefox
                                                      ^^^^^^^ Found it!
```

But if you launched `grep` with arguments that do not match the regex you're grepping for, then that line of `ps`'s output will *not* match the regex.

```
$ ps | grep 'f[ij]refo*x'
```

The unfiltered output will contain a line like

```
thorsen   15820 28618  0 07:28 pts/1    00:00:00 grep f[ij]refo*x
```

but the filtered output won't, because that line doesn't contain any substrings matching the regex `f[ij]refo*x`. (That line doesn't contain `firefx`, or `fjrefx`, or `firefox`, or `fjrefoox`, or...)

But, as jokerdino pointed out, there *can* be something else going on here, too! Because bracket characters are also magic to most *shells*. When you write

```
ls foo*.[ch]
```

the Bash shell actually looks at what files are available in your current working directory and expands that [glob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30229465/what-is-file-globbing) into, like,

```
ls foo.c foobar.c foobar.h
```

If you don't want shell globbing to happen, then you must backslash-escape the magic special characters `*`, `[`, `]` or enclose them in single-quotes:

```
$ ls foo*.[ch]
foo.c   foobar.c        foobar.h

$ ls 'foo*.[ch]'
ls: foo*.[ch]: No such file or directory
```

Globbing also becomes a no-op if Bash can't find any matching files in the current directory:

```
$ rm foo*.[ch]
$ ls foo*.[ch]
ls: foo*.[ch]: No such file or directory
```

So, when you wrote

```
$ grep [f]irefox
```

without any single-quotes, it caused `grep` to look for lines matching the regex `[f]irefox` precisely because *there was no file matching the glob `[f]irefox` in your current working directory!* This doesn't relate to your actual observations, but it's interesting to note that you *could* have observed the following behavior:

```
$ cd /usr
$ ps -ef | grep [f]irefox 
thorsen   16730     1  1 Jun19 ?        00:27:27 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox ....

$ cd /usr/lib
$ ps -ef | grep [f]irefox
thorsen   15820 28618  0 07:28 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto firefox
thorsen   16730     1  1 Jun19 ?        00:27:27 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox ....
```

In the second case here, because the current directory has an entry named `firefox`, the unquoted argument `[f]irefox` is expanded by Bash before `grep` gets to see it, and you end up grepping for the regex `firefox` instead of `[f]irefox`. The solution would be to add single-quotes:

```
$ ps -ef | grep '[f]irefox'
thorsen   16730     1  1 Jun19 ?        00:27:27 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox ....
```

I recommend adding single-quotes around every argument to anything ever, that includes "shell metacharacters" such as `*`, `[`, `(`, `{`, `=`, `,`, `;`, etc. — especially regexes!