# How to print only process numbers for the SSH server in Ubuntu command

Tags: command-line, 20.04

I know we can print every process on the Ubuntu system with this command:

> ps -au

But How to print only process numbers for the SSH server?

Comment: [pgrep, pkill - look up or signal processes based on name and other attributes](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/pgrep.1.html)

Comment: Can you show me the detail command for my purpose

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see just the process numbers, you can use:

```bash
pgrep sshd
```

If you would like to see columns of data with more information than process numbers, you can use:

```bash
pgrep -a sshd
```

or

```bash
ps -aux|grep '[s]shd'
```

See [How does this [t]ricky bracket expression in grep work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153419/how-does-this-tricky-bracket-expression-in-grep-work)